# Unique Validator - add error (warning) and return true

Tags: validation, yii2

What would be the best way to create validator that checks if model value is unique or not, but it does not return false - it only shows message "the value already exists" (I can still save the model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators usually don't return boolean values, they add errors for given model attribute(s).

One of the ways (with minimal completions) will be using built-in [UniqueValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html) and saving without running validation.

At first call `$model->validate()` to fill model with errors.

You can use `$model->validate('fieldName')` to validate only needed field.

Then call `$model->save(false)` or `$model->save('fieldName')` (for just one field).

This will prevent validation before saving and model values will be saved "as is".

Another way for just saving one attribute without triggering events, etc. will be using `updateAttributes` after calling `validate()`:

```
$model->updateAttributes(['fieldName' => 'fieldValue']);
```